# Angular 2: How to delete dynamically created children component

Tags: angular, components

I have a list component and within the list component, there are children items components that are created dynamically using componentFactoryResolver/createComponent. There is a button that allows you to delete the corresponding item component. How can I achieve this? I don't know how to identify the item component (e.g. what is it's index?) that was clicked and destroying that particular component amongst the list of components.

ListComponent.html

```
<button (click)="add()></button>
//this is where the item components will be created
```

ListComponent.ts

```
add() {
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ItemComponent);
    this.itemRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
}
```

ItemComponent.html

```
<button (click)="deleteItem()"></button>
<list-component></list-component>
```

Comment: Doesn't `this.itemRef.destroy()` work?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't destroyit. Would you put this in ItemComponent.ts or the ListComponent.ts?

Comment: Seems to work fine in this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work using this.itemRef.destroy() and an eventEmitter.

Comment: `this.itemRef.destroy()` worked for me.